# Package reference on net framework doesn't load transitive dependencies (not copied in output)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

From scratch :

1. Create a class library A in net framework 4.7.2
2. Reference a nuget package, ex : Newtonsoft
3. Migrate class library A to Package Reference mode
4. Generate nuget package for class library A
5. Create a console application B in net framework 4.7.2
6. Reference class library A
7. Migrate console application B to Package Reference mode

My issue is that Newtonsoft is not copied in output of console application B, so :

If I use a function of A in B which has newtonsoft object in signature : error of compilation => need to reference Newtonsoft in console application B

If I use a function of A in B which use newtonsoft object in its body : error on runtime => FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the link in your response](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5979) Perry Qian-MSFT, I tried to use Msbuild pack instead of nuget.exe in order to pack my package.

It seems to work.

First, need to install the nuget package ["NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack/) in the package to generate.

Then, the command to pack :

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" "D:\Your.csproj" -t:Pack -p:Configuration=Release -p:TargetFramework=net472 -p:PackageOutputPath=D:\NugetPackages -p:Authors="xxx" -p:Version="1.0.0.5"

Perry Qian-MSFT > Maybe the solution of the nuspec is working, but I think the solution of msbuild pack is better because I don't need to edit the nuspec when I update the references

**EDIT :**

After some supplementary tests, it seems that migrate the csproj to the "Microsoft.NET.Sdk" form is another solution. In the case, I need to use the "dotnet pack" command :

> dotnet pack "D:\Your.csproj" -p:Configuration=Release -p:PackageOutputPath=D:\NugetPackages

No need of the "NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack" anymore...

Comment: Nice work. I forget that. Actually, `msbuild pack` is more convenient!

Comment: @Perry Qian-MSFT I edit my response to add another solution I found

Answer (score 1):

**Actually**, it is [a well-known issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5979). `nuget pack` cannot add the dependency of the net framework **Project A** with **PackageReference** into `A.1.0.0.nupkg`. However, when you use `nuget pack` for net framework project with `packages.config`, it can add the dependency automatically for the nupkg.

As a suggestion, you should add the dependency under the `A.nuspec` file

**1)** enter the A project folder by CMD.

**2)** then, run `nuget spec` to [generate the A.nuspec file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#the-role-and-structure-of-the-nuspec-file) and then add these on this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>xxx</id>
    <version>xxx</version>
    <title>xxx</title>
    <authors>xxx</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    ......
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
     <dependencies>      
        <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.3" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

**3)** then run `nuget pack` to generate the new release version. Also, when you install this package, please first clean nuget caches first(delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`)